# OpenCV 2.4.8. Installation from source does not contain \Build\x64\vc10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, cuda

I'm running into trouble when trying to use OpenCV 2.4.8 in Visual Studio 2010. I've built OpenCV from source since i'll be needing CUDA functionality.

When arriving at the step to add the path to the environment variable as indicated here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable, it seems \Build\x64\vc10 is not present in my OpenCV folder. Instead, I've simply added C:\OpenCV\build as OPENCV_DIR to my environment path, since it seems lib and bin are present in this folder.

However, adding $(OPENCV_DIR)....\include to my Visual Studio 2010 project, as indicated here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to will yield unwanted results, as this will point to my C:\ drive, instead of the OpenCV root folder. My OpenCV root folder does have an include folder, however it does not seem to contain relevant files (some files related to CMake).

Long story short, it seems I'm unable to add OpenCV to Visual Studio 2010 if OpenCV is built from source.

Can anybody see what I'm missing here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions assume you are using the prebuilt binaries that come with OpenCV. If you build it yourself (as in your case), you have two options:

1. Set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX when building opencv and run the INSTALL target to put all of the OpenCV files you need in known place that works for you. Set OPENCV_DIR to this installed location (i.e. C:\libs\opencv), and set the include directory to `$(OPENCV_DIR)\include`.
2. set OPENCV_DIR to the build directory (as you've done), but when setting the include directory only go up one directory: `$(OPENCV_DIR)..\include`; this will point to the include directory in the original source location

Comment: Cheers for your explanation. What is the include folder supposed to contain? Mine containst the following:
> cmake_install.cmake
> INSTALL.vcxproj
INSTALL.vcxproj.filters
PACKAGE.vcxproj
PACKAGE.vcxproj.filters
CMakeFiles\generate.stamp
CMakeFiles\generate.stamp.depend

Comment: The include directory should contain just two directories: opencv and opencv2. I think you're looking at the build/include directory. There's also one in the root of the project.